# Apply a function to translate a column in pandas dataframe with condition on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, apply, goslate

data is a pandas dataframe in which language and config['TEXT FIELD'] are columns. I want to translate certain reviews in the text column to english and I am using a function dfApply

```
import goslate
def dfApply(row):
    if row["langauge"] == 'en':
       return row[config['TEXT FIELD']]
    else:
       return gs.translate(row[config['TEXT FIELD']], 'en')


gs = goslate.Goslate()
data['english_text'] = data.apply(dfApply, axis=1)
```

But the complier shows the follwing error

```
KeyError: ('langauge', 'occurred at index 0')
```

Comment: Which line are you getting error in?

Comment: last line where I am applying the  `dfApply` function

Comment: language is a column which referes to which language the text is in

Comment: Why not just convert the whole column to English, then use a mask of non-english rows to replace only the ones you need to?  That is a bit easier than using apply with your conditionals happening in each step.

Comment: The language translator goslate is throwing timeout error for large number of data points

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be an easier approach.

```
not_en = data["language"] != "en"
trans = translate(data[config['row']], "en")
col = config['row']
data.loc[not_en, col] = trans[not_en]
```